# Xamarin.Forms XAML images using 'mipmap' instead of 'drawable' paradigm

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As per the following extract from my XAML file you can see that I like just specifying the name. On iOS it will grab the appropriate dimension e.g. icon_star@2x.png but on Android it seems to prefer drawable-hdpi Resource folder. I was wondering how can I force the Android renderer to look in the mipmap-hdpi folder instead? My understanding is the mipmap folder is the new standard when it comes to stripping out resources for device specific builds.

**Example:**

```xml
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="4">
    <ImageButton Source="icon_star.png" Style="{StaticResource HeaderButtonImage}" Command="{Binding SortNeverVisitedCommand}" />
    <Label Text="NEVER VISITED" Style="{StaticResource HeaderButtonLabel}" />
  </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

According to [this Google blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html):

It’s best practice to place your app icons in **mipmap-** folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.

**However** we now can only consume the drawable folder on Forms.